# Resposive background image

Tags: css, responsive-design

What's the best way to make a background image responsive? I would like the class .container to expand the 16% of the size of the window. I also want text overlaid and vertically/horizontally centered.

Example:
http://codepen.io/zerostyle/pen/avHqG

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cat"><p>CATS ARE AWESOME!</p></div>
</div>

.cat {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/300/300") no-repeat; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;  
  display: table; 
}

.cat p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `background-size` property?

Comment: Yes, not sure how that helps?

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/TM3WF/1/

```
.cat {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/300/300") no-repeat; 
  position: absolute; 
  width:100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  display: table; 
  background-size:cover;
}

.cat p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 

  color:black;
  font-size:24px;    
}
```